# How make tinymce able to upload image in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, tinymce

I am using tinymce in my vue js app but it is not allowing me to upload image .

i am using this package `import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'`
I think i am missing any plugin or tool bar

**component**

```
  

     <editor
                      apiKey="API_KEY"
    
                      :init="{
                       height: 200,
                       menubar: true,
                       plugins: [
                         'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                         'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                         'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount '
                       ],
                        file_picker_types: 'image',
                       toolbar:
                         'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor| link image| \
                         alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                         bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help | image code'
                     }"
    
                    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a option in init object `image_upload_url` OR `image_upload_handler`

docs reference: [tinymce image upload options](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#imageuploadoptions)

First of all you have to create a API endpoint which should response with a json object contains the image path in `location` key, like `{ location: 'path/to/filename.jpg' }`

then,

1. If you use the URL option, you have to provide that endpoint string like `http://example.com/api/image_upload`.
   You have to create that route handler. (I can show you the demo using express)
2. If you use the handler option, needed to provide [this function](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#images_upload_handler), using that API endpoint, and the function should return the same JSON object type.
   (this is for advance use to modify the object before return )

You can use the `image_upload_url` option for simplicity.

I'm using tinymce with express in my own projects.

Let me know what are you using in back-end, so I can assist further.

Comment: Can you please share an example using the node express

Comment: Hey there!
Would you happen to know what to do if I get an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')" when using the handler option?